# what is the meaning of "sequence which has no convergent subsequence"?

Tags: real-analysis

> In a proof of non compactness of the closed unit ball of  $\ell^1$, the author says, the sequence $(e_i)$ with $1$ in the $i$th place and $0$ elsewhere, has no convergent subsequence since $\vert\vert e_i-e_j \vert \vert _1=2$ with $i \neq j$

I don't undetstand what this means. That is, what is the meaning of "the sequence which has no convergent subsequence" ?

Comment: Just what it sounds like.  A sequence that has no convergent subsequence.  Ex: the sequences {1,2,3,4,5,6....} or {1,2,4, 8, 16,....} do not have a convergent subsequenced.  But the sequence $\{1, \frac 12, 2, \frac 14, 3, \frac 18, 4, \frac 1{16}....\}$ which does not converge itself, has a subsequence $\{1, \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18,\frac 1{16}....\}$ which does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that if you create a new sequence out of your initial sequence such that you pick only some terms of the original sequence and leave the others out, the remaining sequence does not converge. In more mathematical terms, if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence and $\{b_k\}$ is a sequence defined by $b_k=a_{n_k}$ such that $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k < \cdots$, then $b_k$ is not convergent.

One may also reword the same statement like this:

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function and define $b_n = a_{f(n)}$. Then $b_n$ is called a subsequence of $a_n$.

Regarding the proof, the author is trying to show that the closed ball in $\ell^1$ is not sequentially compact. Sequential compactness and compactness defined using open covers are equivalent in metric spaces.

Consider $e_1 = (1,0,0,0,0,0,\cdots)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0,0,0,0,\cdots)$

Then, by definiton of the $\ell^1$ norm, we have:

$$\|e_1-e_2\|_1=\sum_n|(e_1)_n-(e_2)_n|=|1-0|+|0-1|=2$$

If instead of $e_1$ and $e_2$ we had $e_i$ and $e_j$, the idea would still be exactly the same.

Comment: For this $\ell_1$ case, the reason is $\vert \vert e_i-e_j \vert \vert=2$. I don't understand this reason

Comment: @LDM I edited my answer. Do you understand it now?

Comment: No! I know how to compute this! I want "how the result follows from this reason"? Is $e_2$ a subsequnce of $e_1$?

Comment: @LDM  well, consider a subsequence of $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. The distance between two different elements of the subsequence is always $2$. If it were to converge to something, the distance had to go to zero. (a converging sequence is Cauchy. Remember?) But the distance between $e_i$ and $e_j$ always remains $2$ no matter what. Hence, it's not Cauchy and it cannot be convergent.

Comment: Now I'm ok! Thanks!